# Windows Phone 7 Boot Startup Receiver Callback WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Does WP7 have have some kind of receiver/callback for when the device is booted up. I would like to schedule some task when the device is started up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Perhaps if you setup a periodic task - you could get some information within about half hour after it starts that it is running, so if it was not reporting as running earlier - you might use this information, but otherwise - your code is pretty much sandboxed and does not know anything about what the system is doing when your application is not running.

Comment: Will the periodic task remain even if the device is rebooted? e.g. if i set a task to reoccur every 5 minutes, if they reboot, will it run 5 minutes after reboot?

Comment: @user848100 the task runs ~every 30 minutes. It doesn't run in battery saver mode. you can't control the frequency

Comment: I see, I was thinking of IScheduler to schedule the task that I need to run. I would need this in intervals of every 5 hours. If you say that periodic task occurs every 30 minutes, then they would not work for me. I'm not too familiar with WP7, could you point me in the right direction to accomplish this? I have some code that I need to run every 5 hours, if the device has been rebooted then I want it to run 5 hours from the time it was rebooted (this should happen in the background without the user needing to start my application).

Comment: + the frequency might change depending on what the OS thinks about your periodic task - anecdotally, if it crashes or uses up too much battery - it might switch to be run every 2 hours or so...

Comment: If it does not need to be exactly 5 hours - if you check the last time your task was run every ~30 minutes - you might be able to do it every 5 hours +/- 15 minutes

Comment: The phone itself has complete control over when it runs periodic tasks.  I heard a really good description while listening to one of the podcasts, and I think it was Shawn Wildermuth doing the explaining.  I don't have it all down pat, but here's what I take away from the explanation:

The phone schedules tasks at times when it is going to be spinning up processes anyway. Turning on the radio is expensive, battery and processor-wise. For this reason, it won't spin up the radio just for a periodic task. It will run the task when it has other tasks scheduled - email, messages, push notes, etc.